# Any way to get Compression method in java using zip4j library?

Tags: java, compression, zip4j

I want to return boolean to check if my zip file is compressed . Will be an advantage if i can also get what Compression method has been used. For now I am just checking is it is Encrypted and is valid zip. Please help if it is possible using zip4j library.

```
public static boolean isPackageCompressed(String path) throws ZipException{
    boolean isPackageCompressed = false;

    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path);

    System.out.println(zipFile.isEncrypted());       
    System.out.println(zipFile.isValidZipFile());        

    // TODO. There is no method like zipFile.getCompressionMethod() . 

    return isPackageCompressed; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        isPackageCompressed("D:\\some.ZIP");
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with zip4j, but with the ZIP format.  In ZIPs the compression method is a property of each entry, it is perfectly valid to mix compression methods in a single archive and you'll encounter a mix of STORED (not compressed at all) and DEFLATEd entries quite often.  You will probably need to iterate over the entries and see whether those are compressed.

Comment: @Stefan Bodewig : Can you please help by sharing some code?

Comment: Using Apache Commons Compress, I could.  :-)  Like I said, I'm not familiar with zip4j.

Comment: @Stefan Bodewig : I couldn't find here any method in Apache Commons also. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveEntry.html

Comment: @Stefan Bodewig : I got it from http://www.java-examples.com/get-compression-method-zip-entry-example , Thanks for the idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out may be helpful (Not the complete answer )

```
ZipParameters zp = new ZipParameters();
zp.setFileNameInZip("sample.zip");
System.out.println(zp.getCompressionMethod());
System.out.println(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);

OutPut:
8
8
```

Comment: Thanks But I don't have any requirement for opening Zip ; just i want to check with what compression method zip file is compressed.

Comment: Thanks :) 
Just for Reference for others :
Compression method :
          0 - The file is stored (no compression)
          1 - The file is Shrunk
          2 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 1
          3 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 2
          4 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 3
          5 - The file is Reduced with compression factor 4
          6 - The file is Imploded
          7 - Reserved for Tokenizing compression algorithm
          8 - The file is Deflated